# Is every function $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ Lebesgue-integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I believe this is the case as the natural numbers have Lebesgue-measure $0$, so the Lebesgue-integral of any function $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ is also $0$. Is that correct?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Typically integration is defined only for measurable functions. So,
at the very least, when talking about Lebesgue integration, you need
to consider mapping from the real line, not $\mathbb{N}$. Having
said that, your intuition is correct: if you extend a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
to $f_{\mathbb{R}}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_{\mathbb{R}}(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if }x\in\mathbb{N}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
then $\int f_{\mathbb{R}}(x)d\mu(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Any $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable if we consider $\mathbb{N} $ to be equipped with the (restricted) sigma algebra and (restricted) Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ has measure zero, one has $\int f^+ = \int f^- = 0$. Hence $\int f = 0$.